# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dentistController'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm getting this error when trying to start my Spring application. My classes are attached below but in a simplified manner.

The projet uses the pattern dto → service → serviceImpl → repository.

**DentistDto.java**

```
@Data
public class DentistDto {

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 11)
    private String croNumber;

    @Valid
    Person person;

}
```

**DentistModel.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "dentists")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class DentistModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "dentist_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 10)
    private String croNumber;

...
```

**DentistController.java**

```
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/dentists")
    @RestController
    public class DentistController {
    
         private final DentistService dentistService;
    
        public DentistController(DentistService dentistService) {
            this.dentistService = dentistService;
        }
    
        @PostMapping
        public ResponseEntity<Object> saveDentist(@RequestBody @Valid DentistDto dentistDto) {
            return dentistService.save(dentistDto);
        }
    
        @GetMapping
        public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllDentists() throws NotFoundException {
            return dentistService.findAll();
        }
...
```

**DentistServiceImpl.java**

```
    @Service
    public class DentistServiceImpl implements DentistService {
    
        private final DentistRepository dentistRepository;
        private final DentistMapper dentistMapper = DentistMapper.INSTANCE;
    
        public DentistServiceImpl(DentistRepository dentistRepository) {
            this.dentistRepository = dentistRepository;
        }
    
        @Override
        public DentistDto findById(UUID id) throws NotFoundException {
            var dentist = dentistRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException());
            return dentistMapper.toDto(dentist);
        }
...
```

**DentistService.java**

```
public interface DentistService {

    DentistDto findById(UUID id) throws NotFoundException;

    ResponseEntity<Object> findAll() throws NotFoundException;

    ResponseEntity<Object> save(DentistDto dto);

...
```

**DentistRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface DentistRepository extends JpaRepository<DentistModel, UUID> {

    Optional<Object> findByCroNumber(String croNumber);
}
```

**DentistMapper.java**

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

    @Mapper
    public interface DentistMapper {
    
        DentistMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(DentistMapper.class);
    
        DentistModel toModel(DentistDto dto);
        DentistDto toDto(DentistModel model);
    }
```

**Full error**

> 24-11-2022 09:46:41.159 | 178  | [main] | INFO  |
> com.api.lores.LoresApplication - Starting the Lores API 24-11-2022
> 09:46:41.312 | 331  | [Thread-0] | DEBUG |
> o.s.b.d.r.c.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@4fb091b
> 24-11-2022 09:46:41.315 | 334  | [restartedMain] | INFO  |
> com.api.lores.LoresApplication - Starting the Lores API 24-11-2022
> 09:46:41.605 | 624  | [restartedMain] | INFO  |
> com.api.lores.LoresApplication - Starting LoresApplication using Java
> 17.0.4.1 on DESKTOP-733E7TU with PID 13984 (C:\Users\Guilherme Lopes\repos\lores\target\classes started by Guilherme Lopes in
> C:\Users\Guilherme Lopes\repos\lores) 24-11-2022 09:46:41.606 | 625  |
> [restartedMain] | INFO  | com.api.lores.LoresApplication - No active
> profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default" 24-11-2022
> 09:46:44.565 | 3584 | [restartedMain] | WARN  |
> o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext -
> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'dentistController' defined in file
> [C:\Users\Guilherme
> Lopes\repos\lores\target\classes\com\api\lores\controller\DentistController.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'dentistServiceImpl' defined in file
> [C:\Users\Guilherme
> Lopes\repos\lores\target\classes\com\api\lores\service\dentist\DentistServiceImpl.class]:
> Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.api.lores.service.dentist.DentistServiceImpl]:
> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 24-11-2022 09:46:44.599 | 3618 |
> [restartedMain] | ERROR | o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run
> failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'dentistController' defined in file
> [C:\Users\Guilherme
> Lopes\repos\lores\target\classes\com\api\lores\controller\DentistController.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'dentistServiceImpl' defined in file
> [C:\Users\Guilherme
> Lopes\repos\lores\target\classes\com\api\lores\service\dentist\DentistServiceImpl.class]:
> Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.api.lores.service.dentist.DentistServiceImpl]:
> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
> at com.api.lores.LoresApplication.main(LoresApplication.java:17)    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'dentistServiceImpl' defined in file
> [C:\Users\Guilherme
> Lopes\repos\lores\target\classes\com\api\lores\service\dentist\DentistServiceImpl.class]:
> Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.api.lores.service.dentist.DentistServiceImpl]:
> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:315)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:296)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
> ... 24 common frames omitted Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.api.lores.service.dentist.DentistServiceImpl]:
> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
> org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:311)
> ... 38 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null   at
> com.api.lores.service.dentist.DentistServiceImpl.(DentistServiceImpl.java:23)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
> ... 40 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for
> com.api.lores.mapper.DentistMapper    at
> org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:61)  at
> com.api.lores.mapper.DentistMapper.(DentistMapper.java:10)
> ... 47 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for
> com.api.lores.mapper.DentistMapper    at
> org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:75)  at
> org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:58)  ... 48
> common frames omitted

**How can I fix this type of error?**

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace instead of a snippet.

Comment: @M.Deinum done, I just edited the post.

Comment: Please add the dentist related entity and controller class.

Comment: @HamzaKhadhri my mistake, I just added the DentistController and DentistModel classes.

Comment: `Cannot find implementation for com.api.lores.mapper.DentistMapper` looks pretty clear to me. I suspect you are using MapStruct and haven't setup compilation correctly.

Comment: According to the stacktrace there is also an error in DentistMapper. Could you add it? It is suspicious that is added via INSTANCE reference - I believe autowiring was expected

Comment: @OlegKondrashov just added the DentistMapper, I do believe that all dentist related classes are posted now.

Comment: @M.Deinum just added the DentistMapper, my mistake again.

Comment: I believe you are doing mapping in a wrong way - you should delete a line with Instance initiation in DentistMapper class, add @Mapper(componentModel = "spring") annotation above this interface and inject it as a bean in a place you need. There is a guide you can refer to - https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct

Comment: You should also add your DentistDto class to check that mapping via mapstruct can be done correctly

Comment: @OlegKondrashov just added the DentistDto too.

Comment: I wasn't telling you to add that class. The stacktrace tells uyou what is wrong. Tehre is no implementation for that interface. You are using mapstruct and you have that setup wrong and thus it won't generate an implementation and thus your application fails to strt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, that stacktrace is badly mangled. It looks like you copied this from a console window with low line width that added plenty of line breaks, then used stack overflow's quote feature to eat all linebreaks. You can obtain a less mangled stack trace by logging to a file rather than a console, or using a console with much larger line width.

Having done that, the stack trace clearly tells you:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for com.api.lores.mapper.DentistMapper
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:75)
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:58) 
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

(in Java, the root cause of an error is usually the last exception in the stack trace)

Now that you know which exception to google, the answer should be much closer at hand :-)

Comment: Thank you so much.

I added `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.api.lores.mapper"})` to my `Application`class and it worked.


I do believe using this annotation I specify the `mapper` package and Spring can managed, right?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add @Service to your DentistService, Like this:

```
@Service
public interface DentistService {

    DentistDto findById(UUID id) throws NotFoundException;

    ResponseEntity<Object> findAll() throws NotFoundException;

    ResponseEntity<Object> save(DentistDto dto);

}
```

Comment: Not working, I keep receiving the same error.

Comment: @guilhermxlopes: did this respond at your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130707/unsatisfied-dependency-expressed-through-constructor-parameter-0-no-qualifying

Comment: That has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: @M.Deinum So how to deal with this error if you know.