# Spring Data JPA Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let me introduce you my code then I will ask a question.
First off all - structure:
[image: Structure]

**Person.java**

```
package com.test.business;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private int id;
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  public Person(){
  }

  public Person(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

//getters and setters
}
```

**PersonRepository.java**

```
package com.test.repository;

import com.test.business.Person;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

}
```

**PersonService.java**

```
package com.test.service;

import com.test.business.Person;
import com.test.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PersonService{

  @Autowired
  private PersonRepository personRepository;

  public void addNewPerson(){
    personRepository.save(new Person(2, "Test2"));
  }
}
```

**PersonController.java**

```
package com.test.controller;

import com.test.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class PersonController {

  @Autowired
  private PersonService personService;

  @GetMapping(value="/")
  @ResponseBody
  public String printWelcome() {
    personService.addNewPerson();
    return "home";
  }
```

**MyWebInitializer.java**

```
package com.test.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyWebInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { RootConfig.class };
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
  }

  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
  }

}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
package com.test.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.test.controller" })
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
  }

  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver
        = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
  }

}
```

**RootConfig.java**

```
package com.test.config;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories( basePackages = {"com.test.repository"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.service", "com.test.repository", "com.test.controller", "com.test.business"})
public class RootConfig {

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
    dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
    dataSource.setPassword("postgres");

    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());

    return factory;
  }

  private Properties jpaProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    return properties;
  }
  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return txManager;
  }

}
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'war'

group 'testApp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:9.0.10'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.0.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.2.Final'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.0.9.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.3'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.3.3.Final'
    compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'
}
```

While building this project there is no errors, but when I try run this app console shows error:

> ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context
>   initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'personService': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'personRepository'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   managed type: class com.test.business.Person

(...)

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Not a managed type: class com.test.business.Person

(...)

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type:
>   class com.test.business.Person

Why is that? Why personService bean could not be create? I have @Entity in Person.java, autowired included, RootConfig contains @ComponentScan

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.service", "com.test.repository", "com.test.controller", "com.test.business"})
```

May you give me advices that help with my problem?

Comment: Where is the entry point to the application, the "main" class? Something like [this class](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/47d9669dbf87ae00b1bff85d99c572834b2d6c2b/server/src/main/java/com/gms/Application.java#L24).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring can't identity your entity classes as valid entities while context initialisation. To make them valid please try one of the following:

1. Change `factory.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());` to `factory.setPackagesToScan("com.test.business");`. Otherwise `com.test.config` package will be used for entity scan.
2. Try to remove `factory.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());` and to put `@EntityScan("com.test.business")` on top of your `RootConfig.java`

See also [Difference between @EntityScan and @ComponentScan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896414/difference-between-entityscan-and-componentscan)

Comment: oh, worked. At start I had all files at the same package but I'v changed this not so log ago. Simple and correct adivce. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set component scan as

```
ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test"})
```

That will work

Comment: You're only scanning controller package that the reason

Comment: Changed this in WebConfig -> not works, still same error so revert this. Changed in RootConfig -> this gives a more errors. For now I will add this error the next comment, in a few minutes I will add this to main post.

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.test.business.Person

Comment: Can i share you a link so you follow that

Comment: @Warmix You need to fix the `factory.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());`, currently it scans the `com.test.config` package but it should scan `com.test.business` instead. See my answer for the details.

Comment: Follow the link. https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-data-jpa-examples/tree/master/query-methods

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.test.service;

import com.test.business.Person;
import com.test.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@DependsOn("personRepository")
public class PersonService{

  @Autowired
  private PersonRepository personRepository;

  public void addNewPerson(){
    personRepository.save(new Person(2, "Test2"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Checked. Something was change. Error still exists but does not include error with personService. What did this change?
I will put next comment shorter error.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.test.business.Person

Comment: Check out @Vladimir Vagaytsev 's answer.  I believe Spring doesnt know aobut your Repo